# 1980's horror TV show

Tags: story-identification, horror

Does anyone know of a show from the 80's where there was a family sitting on a couch, and the couch eats them. A monster family comes out, and the dad is a potato. They sit down and watch a scary show, which is the show that the viewer now watches.

Comment: Sounds like the opening for one of *The Simpson's* treehouse-of-horror halloween shows.

Comment: @JoeL. - That was my first thought

Answer (score 11):

Yep, that's **Monsters**! It was a comedy & horror anthology series that ran between 1988 and 1991 on the Sci-Fi Channel (now Syfy).

[image]